# Calling value in Environment Variable into XML (Windows Terminal Server)

Tags: xml, terminal, environment-variables

I have what I hope is a simple problem. I am unfamiliar with the intricacies of XML as I do not normally use it at this level. I have a small config file for an application that calls the value p:\outputdump at the moment. I need to change this value to an environment variable, for example:

%appdata%\outputdump

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="attachmentDirectory" value="p:\\outputdump\\"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="89.105.96.55" port="25" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    </configuration>
```

Many many thanks in advance for any assistance!

x

Comment: Default XML parsers won't resolve the environment variable. Do you want to have the "value of "%appdata%" in there, or the literal value "%appdata%"?

Comment: Many thanks for the very quick response!

X

I want to have the value of %appdata% in there.

Comment: This is now solved. Like a prat, I'd forgotten that I could write the file on the fly using of all things, DOS and then call the file..